# How to disable num lock warning

Tags: 11.10, login-screen, numlock

In the log in (and lock) screen of Ubuntu 11.10 I get annoying warnings that my Num Lock is on. As it is (on my Desktop) totally irrelevant or Num Lock is enabled or not, is there a way to disable this warning?

Comment: It's maybe irrelevant to you, but not to notebook users.

Comment: @htorque That's true, updated the question to indicate that it is unnecessary for my Desktop.

Comment: See also the following bug in gnome-screensaver: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/835649

Comment: There's also this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/841541

Comment: Whether desktop or notebook is sort of irrelevant: it's bound to be annoying to some people there should be a way to turn this off, shouldn't have to hack the source code. :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the original poster I found this to be slightly annoying. I have checked the code for gnome-screensaver where this is implemented and as far as I can tell it is not configurable. I resorted to editing the source code not to do this and then rebuilding the package. If interested you can the the [rebuilt package](http://fosdick.dyndns.org/ubuntu/gnome-screensaver_3.2.0-0ubuntu1local1_amd64.deb) or a [patch you can apply yourself](http://fosdick.dyndns.org/ubuntu/debian-changes-3.2.0-0ubuntu1local1).

To install the package once downloaded, in a shell (terminal window) do:

```
dpkg -i gnome-screensaver_3.2.0-0ubuntu1local1_amd64.deb
```

I am not proposing to send the patch upstream as this really is a hack because the rebuilt package is less than ideal for laptops where numlock makes some of the alphabetic keys generate numbers.

Comment: Will this work for 16.04?