# Disable numlock warning on lock screen for notebook

Tags: keyboard, password, lock-screen, numlock

I own a notebook with separate number pad on the keyboard and running 16.04.

On the login screen/lock screen, I see a grey warning triangle in the password input field telling me that NUM-Lock is on.

However, as this keyboard has a separate number pad which is not integrated into the letter keys, I don't need this warning. If I remember correctly, the warning is not existing on desktop installations at all anyway.

How can I disable this warning? I want the CAPS-Lock warning to remain enabled though.

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1526322?

Comment: Note this is a dupe from a previous version: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64382/how-to-disable-num-lock-warningThis also occurs on my dekstop on 16.04, would like to remove it as it always makes me think capslock is on, or that there is a genuine problem. I actually consider it a problem when NUM-lock is *off*, so...yeah. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has recently been fixed in a Unity update for 16.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1526322/comments/9

Comment: Do you know whether (and when) the fix will be backported to 16.04?

Comment: I believe it will be backported at some point but I don't have confirmation or an ETA yet.